# N Queens and state of result

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking

I'm currently working on the [N Queens problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-queens/), and I've got a solution that's very close, but not returning anything for some reason:

```
class Solution:
    def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> List[List[str]]:
        result = []
        placements = []
        self.solveNQueensR(n, 0, placements, result)
        return result
    
    def solveNQueensR(self, n: int, row: int, placements: List[str], result: List[List[str]]):
        if n == row:
            result.append(placements)
        else:
            for i in range(n):
                if self.isValid(row, i, placements):
                    placements = self.addQueen(n, i, placements)
                    self.solveNQueensR(n, row + 1, placements, result)
                    placements.pop(-1)
        return None
    
    def addQueen(self, n: int, col: int, placements: List[str]):
        string = ('.' * col) + 'Q' + ('.' * (n - col - 1))
        placements.append(string)
        return placements
    
    def isValid(self, rowToPlace: int, col: int, placements: List[str]):
        for i, row in enumerate(placements):
            queen = row.index('Q')
            if queen == col or abs(queen - col) == rowToPlace - i:
                return False
        return True
```

For some reason, this outputs `[[],[]]`. If you print the result, you can see the result is actually correct at some point in time, but I believe what's happening is that it's appending `placements` to results and then this line `placements.pop(-1)` is modifying placements, thus affecting the result. How do I prevent this? I tried doing `placements = placements[:-1]` instead, but that just broke it.

Comment: What is `placements.pop(-1)` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Instead of `result.append(placements)` do `result.append(placements[:])`

Comment: Your solution relies on mutating lists on line 5, 10, 14, 15, 16 and 21. You tried to fix your solution by removing the list mutation on line 16 without also updating the rest. It's much easier to go with @trincot's suggestion of copying the list when you add it to the result, because that's a single line fix instead of a 6+ line fairly fundamental rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe what's happening is that it's appending `placements` to `results` and then this line `placements.pop(-1)` is modifying `placements`, thus affecting the result.

That's indeed the reason. During the whole process, `placements` refers to one single list. Never is there a new list instance created for it, so every time `result.append(placements)` is executed, `result` receives a reference to the *same* list.

A solution is to take a copy of `placements` and append the copy to `results`. That way you're sure that what is appended never changes afterwards:

```
result.append(placements[:])
```